# Extjs - select a specific grid row using Component Query

Tags: extjs, grid, component-query

I need to dynamically change the value contained within a grid panel row, but I don't know how to go about selecting the row - can I perhaps use ComponentQuery to select it?

I have a hidden column with a unique identifier that I would like to use as the selector but I'm not sure if this is possible and, if so, what the syntax would be.

Any guidance appreciated.

[Edit] To clarify, I want to simply change what is presented to the user in the grid row, and not update any underlying data - perhaps this is not possible?

Answer (score 0):

You don't change the data in the grid by changing the row, you change it by updating the underlying model:

```
store.first().set('myField', 1);
```

Comment: Thanks, I see what you are saying, but I don't want to change any underlying data, just what is presented to the user (I wish to indicate progress, something like 'Category - 1 of 5 completed' - as my row represents a grouping of child elements). Is this technically possible?

Answer (score 0):

You may find **[column renderer](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column-cfg-renderer)** helpful.

```
renderer: function(value){
    if (value === 1) {
        return '1 person';
    }
    return value + ' people';
}
```

But I am not quite sure if they are exactly what you are looking for, cause they only allow manipulation of the viewed data at rendertime. If this is not fitting you should describe a scenario.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion, although as you surmise I need to update the rows more than once. I have another panel which is updated with different content, and a checkbox in this panel indicates that this content has been viewed - this drives a progress indicator which is what I need to update on the grid rows. Is there way I can force the grid to rerender, thus making use of the column renderer?

Comment: @BrynJ well, the only way that work automaticly would be the update of the target record. Each update force the grid to update the view and thus rerun the renderer. Is there any reason way you can't change the record to which you apply the renderer? If not do it, you just need the id to fetch it from the store and after that use set('fieldname',newvalue);. Hope that helps!

Comment: As you say, I think that updating the store record is the only solution. My thinking around not updating the record was because I need to retain the original value to rebuild the row with a progress indicator - to explain, it's in the format 'Original Row Value - 1 of 5'. How might I use the set method to retain the value but update the progress indicator? Note that I have already the code to track progress, naturally :)

Comment: @BrynJ  OK. I think you will have to add either a extra field to the record or write your own column type which then contains your process indicator. I strongly recommend you the first one, cause columns should only geht affected by records. Another approach may be a local store where the renderer write the origin value along with the record key so that you can fetch it back from there of you have the need.